# Volume Integral over Oscillatory Function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, oscillatory-integral

I want to calculate the definite integral
$$ I = \int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1 \operatorname{m} (x,y,z) e^{i \phi(x,y,z)} dx dy dz$$
where
$$ \operatorname{m}(x,y,z) = m_0 + m_1 x + m_2 y + m_3z + m_4xy + m_5xz+ m_6yz+ m_7xyz \quad m _n\in \mathbb{R} $$
and
$$ \operatorname{\phi}(x,y,z) = p_0 + p_1 x + p_2 y + p_3z + p_4xy + p_5xz+ p_6yz+ p_7xyz  \quad p _n\in \mathbb{R}$$
I know that the first integral can be solved by finding a parameterisation $h_x(p)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)+i p)$ and using
$$ \int_{0}^x \operatorname{m} (x,y,z) e^{i \phi(x,y,z)} dx = \\e^{i \phi(1,y,z)} \int_0^\infty \operatorname{m} (h_0(\rho),y,z)e^{-p}h^\prime_0(\rho)d\rho - e^{i \phi(0,y,z)}\int_0^\infty \operatorname{m} (h_1(\rho),y,z)e^{-p}h^\prime_1(\rho)d\rho $$
Having done this, i could probably do this 'trick' again on each new integral of the form $\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1f(y,z)e^{ig(y,z)} dy dz$ and then again to integrate over $z$. But this leads to long expressions that are not manageable by hand or even mathematica.
Any advice how to proceed? 
I did a brief literature research on oscillatory integrals, which lead to the hint with the parametrisation that i used for the first integral, but i couldn't find a generalisation for volume integrals over oscillating functions. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you use the fact that:
$$(ax+by+cz)^2=a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2+2(abxy+acxz+bcyz)$$
and use a substitution for $(x,y,z)\to(u,v,w)$ that way?

Comment: I managed to rephrase my problem into this:Is there a basis set in which $ \operatorname{\phi}(x,y,z)$ can be expanded so that the integral 
$$ I = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{i \phi(x,y,z)} \operatorname{dx} \operatorname{dy} \operatorname{dz}$$
can be expressed in a closed form?